# Fetching api with nlohmann/json

Tags: c++, json, api, c++11, nlohmann-json

I want to use api with c++ and when I searched I found nlohmann/json library it looks really popular but no one talks about how to get the array that fetch function  provides . How can I get the information  from the api as variables in my cpp file

Answer (score 0):

Didn’t quite understand your description, I assume you mean you want to get the JSON array? You can try this:

```
std::string ss= R"(
{
    "test-data":
    [
        {
            "name": "tom",
            "age": 11
        },
        {
            "name": "jane",
            "age": 12
        }
    ]
}
)";

json myjson = json::parse(ss);

auto &students = myjson["test-data"];

for(auto &student : students) {
    cout << "name=" << student["name"].get<std::string>() << endl;
}
```